# SQL datetime proximity against a set

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

server: sql 2008 R2; dataset: between 50-100 million records

I have a table full of speed instances for vehicles from which I need to determine the average speed of all the cars (ie one number not a number for each car). The trick is the records span a great period of time and there is no consistency to the time when the records where recorded so I may have a recording at 8:15 for a car and nothing again until 8:20 whereas another car might have records for every 10 seconds inside that time period.

Given a specific date and time I need to determine this average speed and since it is most likely there will not be a direct match between the given time and a recording for that car, I need to choose the speed from the recording closest to the given time.

Here is a setup script

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SpeedRecords](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CarId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TimeOfEntry] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Speed] [real] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_SpeedRecords] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC))
go
insert into SpeedRecords(CarId,TimeOfEntry,Speed)
select 1, '11/22/2010 08:16:13', 67.56 union
select 1, '11/22/2010 08:15:23', 63.87 union
select 1, '11/22/2010 08:36:33', 45.66 union
select 1, '11/22/2010 08:23:43', 56.87 union
select 2, '11/22/2010 08:36:53', 78.66 union
select 2, '11/22/2010 08:04:03', 34.88 union
select 2, '11/22/2010 08:08:51', 23.23 union
select 2, '11/22/2010 08:34:52', 65.87 union
select 3, '11/22/2010 08:58:43', 45.34 union
select 3, '11/22/2010 08:34:56', 73.23 union
select 3, '11/22/2010 08:12:34', 12.87 union
select 4, '11/22/2010 08:45:12', 66.45 union
select 4, '11/22/2010 08:36:34', 90.87 union
select 4, '11/22/2010 08:24:23', 34.89 union
select 4, '11/22/2010 08:45:12', 45.83


declare @dt datetime = '11/22/2010 08:43:14'
-- select the average speed (for all cars) but 
-- only use the record for each car closest to 
-- the given datetime (@dt)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ABS(DATEDIFF..) to work out smallest difference, ORDER on that, restrict.

Change [ROW_NUMBER() to DENSE_RANK()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx) if you want the average of 2 speeds that are the same difference from @dt

```
declare @dt datetime = '11/22/2010 08:43:14'
-- select the average speed (for all cars) but 
-- only use the record for each car closest to 
-- the given datetime (@dt)

;WITH Closest AS
(
     SELECT
        Speed,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(second,@dt,TimeOfEntry))) AS Ranking
     FROM
        SpeedRecords

)
SELECT
    AVG(Speed)
FROM
    Closest
WHERE
    Ranking = 1
```

For SQL Server 2000 you'd need a correlated subquery and TOP but it'd be awkward